# ¿Hay alguna manera de guardar el estado de los widgets en Tkinter en Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

Tengo una pequeña interfaz gráfica con algunos widgets como casillas de verficación y botones de radio, por lo cual quiero que al cerrar la ventana  por medio de un botón se guarde el estado anterior de cada widget presente en la ventana y al volver a abrila se carge el estado anterior guardado.

Este es el código en el que he estado trabajando:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('230x333')
root.geometry('+360+20')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title('Opciones')
root.maxsize(230, 333)
root.minsize(230, 333)

styleCheck = ttk.Style(root)                                                                
styleCheck.configure('A.TCheckbutton', font=("Tahoma", 8)) #Estilo de widget (opcional)

CheckVar = tk.IntVar()
CheckBtn= ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Casilla de verificación 1", variable=CheckVar, style='A.TCheckbutton', takefocus=False)
CheckBtn.place(x=10, y=14)

CheckVar2 = tk.IntVar()
CheckBtn2= ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Casilla de verificación 2", variable=CheckVar2, style='A.TCheckbutton', takefocus=False)
CheckBtn2.place(x=10, y=47)

CheckVar3 = tk.IntVar()
CheckBtn3= ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Casilla de verificación 3", variable=CheckVar3, style='A.TCheckbutton', takefocus=False)
CheckBtn3.place(x=10, y=80)

labelframeOptions = tk.LabelFrame(root, text = 'Botones de radio', fg="blue", font=("Tahoma", 8))
labelframeOptions.place(x=12, y=108)

labelFrameSize=tk.Label(labelframeOptions, text="", font=("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8), width=33, height=8)
labelFrameSize.pack() # Así establezco la altura y el ancho del GroupBox o el LabelFrame.

styleRad = ttk.Style()
styleRad.configure('S.TRadiobutton', font=("Tahoma", 8)) #Estilo de widget (opcional)

RadButtonVariable = tk.IntVar() # Puse sola una variable ya que es un grupo de opciones dependientes de solo una selección.

RadBtn = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Selección de opción 1", value=0, style='S.TRadiobutton', variable=RadButtonVariable, takefocus=False)
RadBtn.place(x=25, y=130)

RadBtn2 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Selección de opción 2", value=1, style='S.TRadiobutton', variable=RadButtonVariable, takefocus=False)
RadBtn2.place(x=25, y=150)

RadBtn3 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Selección de opción 3", value=2, style='S.TRadiobutton', variable=RadButtonVariable, takefocus=False)
RadBtn3.place(x=25, y=170)

RadBtn4 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Selección de opción 4", value=3, style='S.TRadiobutton', variable=RadButtonVariable, takefocus=False)
RadBtn4.place(x=25, y=190)

def enableTestButton(): # Función de habilitar botón (No guarda nada, el estado se piensa guardar en otra función)
    if CheckVar4.get()==True:
        btnExample.config(state='normal')

    else:
        btnExample.config(state='disabled')


CheckVar4 = tk.IntVar()
CheckBtn4= ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Ejemplo habilitar botón", variable=CheckVar4, style='A.TCheckbutton', takefocus=False, command=enableTestButton)
CheckBtn4.place(x=10, y=243) # Casilla verificación para habilitar el botón

styleButtons = ttk.Style(root)                                                                
styleButtons.configure('S.TButton', font=("Tahoma", 8)) #Estilo de widget (opcional)

btnExample = ttk.Button(root, text='Boton prueba', style= 'S.TButton', takefocus=False, state='disabled') # Ejemplo de botón deshabilitado predeterminado
btnExample.place(x=145,y=242)

btnSaveSettings = ttk.Button(root, text='Guardar', style= 'S.TButton', takefocus=False, command=root.destroy) # La idea es que el botón de Guardar destruya la ventana pero guardando los cambios
btnSaveSettings.place(x=63,y=300)                                                                              # Todos los cambios que se realizen deben estar en una función anónima para guardar cada estado.

btnCancelSettings = ttk.Button(root, text='Cancelar', style= 'S.TButton', takefocus=False, command=root.destroy) # El botón Cancelar en todo programa solo destruye la ventana ejecutando solo un evento de destrucción de ventana sin guardar o agregar nada.
btnCancelSettings.place(x=145,y=300)

# El protocolo de cierre de ventana (WM_DELETE_WINDOW) es el mismo que el del botón Cancelar no guarda nada y destruye la ventana.
root.mainloop()
```

Es un poco simple el código pero es concreta la pregunta. Si bien mi objetivo es que se almacene en un archivo *.ini o un archivo de configuración cada estado del widget o de la variable para poder luego abrir la ventana y cargar el estado que quedo guardado, hay alguna forma rápida y sencilla de poder almacenar el estado de los widgets en general y cargarlos? En otros lenguejes de programación utilizan un archivo *.xml o archivos predefinidos como archivos *.settings en el caso de c#. Pero hay alguna manera en Tkinter que sea concreta y que funcione. Agradezco su respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo con su pregunta, no hay formas rápidas o ya generadas en el caso de Tkinter para guardar el estado de los widgets en la ventana, hay varias soluciones que usted puede aplicar como usar el módulo `configparser` (*.ini) o el módulo `pickle` para almacenar cada variable del widget puede ser una cadena o una variable entera entre otras... En el caso de `pickle` usted puede usar Serialización de objetos, en otras palabras cada objeto presente es convertido en una estructura binaria y se puede ordenar en una estructura simple definiendo cada variable por medio de una función la cual se encarga de recopilar cada variable del widget por medio del método `dump()` y luego al cerrar la ventana lee la función encargada de leer el archivo *.pickle para reconfigurar los widgets presentes usando el método `load()`.

En mi caso en los programas que he hecho yo aplico una solución un poco sencilla y simple la cual se basa en agregar un archivo de texto y definir en una lista cada definición para cada variable entera `IntVar()` que voy a usar en el widget, luego guardo los valores de cada variable y al iniciar la ventana se lee el archivo y reconfigura los estados de los widgets. Esto aplica para casillas de verificación o botones de radio.

**Nota:** Si usted quiere guardar por así decirlo el estado visible como `disabled` o `normal` de un botón o widget en especial, solo es cuestión de recargar la función, al leer el archivo de configuración leerá la función de la casilla de verificación y se reconfigurará el estado del widget.

Analizando su código al ver una casilla que habilita un botón el método está en recargar la función que ejecuta la casilla de verificación dependiendo del estado guardado se reconfigura el estado.
Aquí está la solución de acuerdo a su problema:

```
import tkinter 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os

root = tk.Tk() 
root.geometry('230x333')
root.geometry('+360+20')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title('Opciones')
root.maxsize(230, 333)
root.minsize(230, 333)

if not os.path.exists('UserSettings.cfg'):
    with open('UserSettings.cfg', 'w') as fileSettings:
        fileSettings = open("UserSettings.cfg", "a")
        fileSettings.write("CheckBoxState1 0 CheckBoxState2 0 CheckBoxState3 0 CheckBoxState4 0 \n")
        fileSettings.close()

try:

    if not os.path.exists('UserSettings.cfg'):
        with open('UserSettings.cfg', 'w') as fileSettings:
            fileSettings.read() # Lee archivo de configuración

except:
    print('Se agrega un archivo de configuración')

try:
    if os.path.isfile('UserSettings.cfg'):
        with open("UserSettings.cfg", "r") as fileSettings:
            lineList = fileSettings.readlines()
            _, Setting1, _, Setting2, _, Setting3, _, Setting4 = lineList[-1].split() # Orden de definiciones para las variables de las casillas de verificación (No modificar si no sabe)
                                                                                  # La lista se guardará en un archivo con extensión *.cfg Si se altera esta estructura los ajustes podrían no funcionar o no cargarán.
    else:
        Setting1 = '0' # Cada definición debe conectar a la variable (CheckVar). Valor predeterminado = 0 (No recomendable modificar)
        Setting2 = '0'
        Setting3 = '0'
        Setting4 = '0'


except Exception as error:
    print('Error')

styleCheck = ttk.Style(root)                                                                 
styleCheck.configure('A.TCheckbutton', font=("Tahoma", 8)) #Estilo de widget (opcional)

CheckVar = tk.IntVar()
CheckBtn= ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Casilla de verificación 1", variable=CheckVar, style='A.TCheckbutton', takefocus=False)
if Setting1 == '1':
    CheckVar.set(1)
CheckBtn.place(x=10, y=14)

CheckVar2 = tk.IntVar()
CheckBtn2= ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Casilla de verificación 2", variable=CheckVar2, style='A.TCheckbutton', takefocus=False)
if Setting2 == '1':
    CheckVar2.set(1)
CheckBtn2.place(x=10, y=47)

CheckVar3 = tk.IntVar()
CheckBtn3= ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Casilla de verificación 3", variable=CheckVar3, style='A.TCheckbutton', takefocus=False)
if Setting3 == '1':
    CheckVar3.set(1)
CheckBtn3.place(x=10, y=80)

labelframeOptions = tk.LabelFrame(root, text = 'Botones de radio', fg="blue", font=("Tahoma", 8)) 
labelframeOptions.place(x=12, y=108)

labelFrameSize=tk.Label(labelframeOptions, text="", font=("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8), width=33, height=8)
labelFrameSize.pack() # Así establezco la altura y el ancho del GroupBox o el LabelFrame.

styleRad = ttk.Style()
styleRad.configure('S.TRadiobutton', font=("Tahoma", 8)) #Estilo de widget (opcional)

if not os.path.exists('SelectedRadioButton.cfg'):
    with open('SelectedRadioButton.cfg', 'w') as fileSettingRadio:
        fileSettingRadio = open("SelectedRadioButton.cfg", "a")
        fileSettingRadio.write("CursorSelection 0 \n")
        fileSettingRadio.close()


try:

    if not os.path.exists('SelectedRadioButton.cfg'):
        with open('SelectedRadioButton.cfg', 'w') as fileSettingRadio1:
            fileSettingRadio1.read() # Lee archivo de configuración

except:
    print('Se agrega un archivo de configuración')

try:
    if os.path.isfile('SelectedRadioButton.cfg'):
        with open("SelectedRadioButton.cfg", "r") as fileSettingRadio2:
            lineList = fileSettingRadio2.readlines()
            _, SettingRadio = lineList[-1].split() # Orden de definiciones para las variables de radiobuttons (No modificar si no sabe)
                                                                                  # La lista se guardará en un archivo con extensión *.cfg Si se altera esta estructura los ajustes podrían no funcionar o no cargarán.
    else:
        SettingRadio = '0' # Cada definición debe conectar a la variable (RadButtonVariable). Valor predeterminado = 0 (No recomendable modificar)

except Exception as error:
    print('Error')

RadButtonVariable = tk.IntVar() # Puse sola una variable ya que es un grupo de opciones dependientes de solo una selección.

RadBtn = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Selección de opción 1", value=0, style='S.TRadiobutton', variable=RadButtonVariable, takefocus=False)
if SettingRadio == '0':
    RadButtonVariable.set(0)
RadBtn.place(x=25, y=130)

RadBtn2 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Selección de opción 2", value=1, style='S.TRadiobutton', variable=RadButtonVariable, takefocus=False)
if SettingRadio == '1':
    RadButtonVariable.set(1)
RadBtn2.place(x=25, y=150)

RadBtn3 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Selección de opción 3", value=2, style='S.TRadiobutton', variable=RadButtonVariable, takefocus=False)
if SettingRadio == '2':
    RadButtonVariable.set(2)
RadBtn3.place(x=25, y=170)

RadBtn4 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="Selección de opción 4", value=3, style='S.TRadiobutton', variable=RadButtonVariable, takefocus=False)
if SettingRadio == '3':
    RadButtonVariable.set(3)
RadBtn4.place(x=25, y=190)

def enableTestButton(): # Función de habilitar botón (No guarda nada, el estado se piensa guardar en otra función)
    if CheckVar4.get()==True:
        btnExample.config(state='normal')

    else: 
        btnExample.config(state='disabled')


CheckVar4 = tk.IntVar()
CheckBtn4= ttk.Checkbutton(root, text="Ejemplo habilitar botón", variable=CheckVar4, style='A.TCheckbutton', takefocus=False, command=enableTestButton)
if Setting4 == '1':
    CheckVar4.set(1)
CheckBtn4.place(x=10, y=243) # Casilla verificación para habilitar el botón

styleButtons = ttk.Style(root)                                                                 
styleButtons.configure('S.TButton', font=("Tahoma", 8)) #Estilo de widget (opcional)

btnExample = ttk.Button(root, text='Boton prueba', style= 'S.TButton', takefocus=False, state='disabled') # Ejemplo de botón deshabilitado predeterminado
btnExample.place(x=145,y=242)

enableTestButton()

def saveSettings():
    fileSettings2 = open("UserSettings.cfg", "a")
    fileSettings2.write("CheckBoxState1 %d CheckBoxState2 %d CheckBoxState3 %d CheckBoxState4 %d \n" % (CheckVar.get(), CheckVar2.get(), CheckVar3.get(), CheckVar4.get()))
    fileSettings2.close()

def saveSettingsRadioButtons():
    fileRadioSelections = open("SelectedRadioButton.cfg", "a")
    fileRadioSelections.write("SelectedRadioButton %d \n" % (RadButtonVariable.get()))
    fileRadioSelections.close()     

btnSaveSettings = ttk.Button(root, text='Guardar', style= 'S.TButton', takefocus=False, command=lambda:[saveSettings(), saveSettingsRadioButtons(), root.destroy()]) # La idea es que le botón de Guardar destruya la ventana pero guardando los cambios
btnSaveSettings.place(x=63,y=300)                                                                              # Todos los cambios que se realicen deben estar en una función anónima para guardar cada estado.

btnCancelSettings = ttk.Button(root, text='Cancelar', style= 'S.TButton', takefocus=False, command=root.destroy) # El botón Cancelar en todo programa solo destruye la ventana ejecutando solo un evento de destrucción de ventana sin guardar o agregar nada.
btnCancelSettings.place(x=145,y=300)

# El protocolo de cierre de ventana (WM_DELETE_WINDOW) es el mismo que el del botón Cancelar no guarda nada y destruye la ventana.
root.mainloop()
```

Espero que esta solución le sirva a usted, en mi caso todos los métodos anteriores funcionan, en el caso de `pickle` lo uso más que todo para guardar valores dentro de la lista de un `Combobox` pero en general esos métodos son válidos. Para más información consulte la documentación de los módulos [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/pickle.html) y [Configparser](https://docs.python.org/es/3.10/library/configparser.html).

**Para evidenciar los resultados:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad por la explicación y por ayudarme ya que no encontraba ninguna solución más concreta y simple como la que pusiste por supuesto me enfocaré en aprender a usar también ambos modulos, pero en general le agradezco era justo lo que necesitaba.